# Could not find sprockets-2.12.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

When I try to run a rails migration:

> rails g migration AddPictureToBikes

I get this message:

> Could not find sprockets-2.12.3 in any of the sources
>
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

This is weird because the bundle is able to be completed when I run bundle install. It even says that its using sprockets:

> Using sprockets 2.12.3

I'll appreciate it if anyone could tell me how I could fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check where your gem in question is with `bundle show sprockets`. Next, there is a preferred  check list to do to troubleshoot bundler issues, please see [Bundler issues](http://bundler.io/issues.html). Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

I can not add a comment, so I have to put my suggestion here.
You can check your gemset to see if there is something wrong.